# VS2012 IDE Drag & drop file into code doesn't work anymore

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I used to be able to drag CSS or JS files from my solution explorer into the HTML and it would create the necessary references.  This no longer works and I'm not sure why.

I know it's petty, but I just got so used to it and I miss it :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you have to be in a asp.net solution or project for this feature to work.  I created a new project and imported the exact HTML file and now the drag & drop functionality has returned.

[image: Are you kidding me?]